# Maven: is $HOME/.m2/repository purely a cache?

Tags: maven

i.e, can I delete it at any time with the only side effect is that it must be repopulated when projects are built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository contains any artifacts which have been cached from remote repositories and any artifacts which you have installed using `mvn install`

If you have never installed any artifacts locally, then you can consider it a cache, and delete it without concern.